# See details of Tomcat child process

Tags: linux, tomcat, process, ps

I have an application that were deployed with .war into a tomcat.

I am getting some CPU consumation problems about this application and I'd like to see some details about processes of it.
But when I run top, I just get something like this:

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 **2310 app1       20   0 11.1g 1.4g  11m S 191.3 14.5  31:32.67 java**
   21 root      20   0     0    0    0 S 11.7  0.0   0:29.89 ksoftirqd/4
 3387 xymon     20   0 15156 1176  792 R  2.0  0.0   0:00.01 top
    1 root      20   0 19352 1528 1212 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.54 init

But this only shows that tomcat/java is consuming my CPU.
I would like to see what child process of that tomcat is the problem,
but with the top command, only see the tomcat process.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure JMX to see details of which process/threads is consuming time.

Below Java_OPTS can be configured for JMX.

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Once that is done you can use Jconsole or JVisualVM in JDK directory as part of JDK installation